# How to change spacing between \cventry blocks?

Tags: moderncv

I am using package `moderncv` to write my CV. I have several `\cventry` blocks. Now I would like to globally change the spacing between the end of block `A` and the following block `B`. Is that possible?

I found out that you can use `\cventry[10em]`, however, it is not working in my case.

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[9][.25em]{% 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% 
{\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\% 
{\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\% 
{#7} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\\ {#8} & \\}%
\end{tabular*}% 
}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry[10em]{Grade}{Degree}{Institution}{year--year}{M.Sc.}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `\par\addvspace{#1}%` like

```
.
.
.
\end{tabular*}%
\par\addvspace{#1}%
}
```

In your definition, you left `#1`, hence `10em` had no effect.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[9][.25em]{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
{\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
{\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
{#7} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\\ {#8} & \\}%
\end{tabular*}%
\par\addvspace{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry[10em]{Grade}{Degree}{Institution}{year--year}{M.Sc.}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I will accept your answer officially as soon as I am allowed to.